# PHP won't load with php.ini file in place

Tags: php, macos

I have set up a MAMP server on my local computer.

The server runs fine, no problems, but I need to install the mcrypt extension on PHP as I need to install Laravel.

I've been following this tutorial:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

I have an issue with the last step. When I create a new php.ini file using the following Terminal command, PHP refuses to run at all.

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Basically with no php.ini file in the etc/ folder, the PHP works fine (PHP info pages load, sites using PHP run fine), but when it's in place, no PHP works and loading a PHP info page returns a blank white browser window.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you changed permissions? It could be trying to write the php ini file but not having access to it?

Comment: As I remember, MAMP has custom path for php.ini. Look for any etc or conf or bin dir in the MAMP directory (into Applications dir). There is already a php.ini into one of these dirs.

Comment: @BradlySpicer I changed permissions of the php.ini file to read & write but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: When viewing PHP info, the path shows correctly as /etc It also says scan this directory for additional .ini files but the directory does not exist: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php

Comment: Also tried copying the php.ini file into the above directory which I created and still get the same problem.

Comment: Also when I do php --ini in Terminal it says the correct path to the php.ini file, which leads me to believe there's an issue with the php.ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to figure out the issue, here's the solution for anyone stumbling on this in the future.

short_open_tags was disabled in the php.ini file. I simply enabled this, saved the file to the /etc folder and rebooted the Apache server and it works great now. I needed to modify the php.ini file again to add the mycrypt extension but now works great.

Comment: That's why you should never use short-open-tags... don't be lazy, don't make your code harder to read then necessary and just use the normal tags.